# Binary search function function, domain and max number of iterations as parameters

Tags: python

I'm quite new to python and algorithms, I'm struggling with the following function. Can anyone assist?:

For this question, you will be required to use the binary search to find the root of some function  ()  on the domain  ∈[,]  by continuously bisecting the domain. In our case, the root of the function can be defined as the x-values where the function will return 0, i.e.  ()=0
For example, for the function:  ()=2()2−2  on the domain  [0,2] , the root can be found at  ≈1.43 .

Constraints

Stopping criteria:  ||()||<0.0001  or you reach a maximum of 1000 iterations.
Round your answer to two decimal places.
Function specifications

Argument(s):

f (function)  →  mathematical expression in the form of a lambda function.
domain (tuple)  →  the domain of the function given a set of two integers.
MAX (int)  →  the maximum number of iterations that will be performed by the function.

My current solution is not quite there:

````
### START FUNCTION
def binary_search(f, domain, MAX = 1000):
    
### END FUNCTION```

---------------------------------

Required input:

f = lambda x:(np.sin(x)**2)*(x**2)-2
domain = (0,2)
x = binary_search(f,domain)
x

----------------------------------

Expected output:
1.43
````

Comment: `MAX - 1` does nothing, you probably want to do  `MAX = MAX - 1` (or equivalently `MAX -= 1`) don't you?

Comment: You should probably include all stopping conditions in the while loop condition: `while abs(f(mid)) < 0.0001 and MAX > 0:`

Comment: Thanks for the help guys, im not completely sure how to change the code after using the while loop? I did change the MAX -= 1.

Comment: @Pangaman89 One thing to be noted here is this binary-search method will only work if function is monotonically increasing or decreasing in the domain. This function meets this criteria, so its all good.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only thing your code miss is the reassignment of the variable `MAX`:

```py
MAX = MAX - 1
```

Then I obtain as expected 1.43.

And as noticed by @Stef, including the conditions in the `while` loop would be cleaner than using `return` in the middle. Currently, your loop is equivalent to a `while True` as `start` will always be smaller than `end` (assuming that the passed domain is in the right order).

This should be a bit cleaner:

```py
def binary_search(f, domain, MAX = 1000):
    start, end = domain
    if start >= end:
        raise ValueError("Domain is empty")
    mid = (start + end) / 2
    fmid = f(mid)
    step = 0
    while abs(fmid) > 0.0001 and step < MAX:
        if fmid < 0:
            start = mid
        else:
            end = mid
        mid = (start + end) / 2
        fmid = f(mid)
        step += 1
    return round(mid, 2)
```

Comment: I can't really understand as you can't post blocks of code in comments, but it looks similar to my version

Comment: my bad, new to Stackoverflow :D

That seems to do the trick thank you very much,

Comment: @leleogere Your code will only end after `MAX` iterations. Even when you reach the desired accuracy much earlier, you will always do `MAX` iterations. It doesn't set right with me, but of course it will give you the correct answer.

Comment: No problem, I'm quite new too! So don't hesitate to mark the answer as accepted if it works for you :)

Comment: @Pangaman89 If you find this answer helpful, consider accepting it :)

Comment: @vish4071 if we get to the asked tolerance, the loop will break as the first condition will not be met anymore

Comment: Oh @leleogere, my bad....you are right

Comment: No problem, I could have done such an error to be honest

Comment: (I improved the code a bit using the variable `fmid` to do only one computation of `f(mid)` per loop instead of two)

Comment: I don't know how the mark is computed, but for your example it does give 1.43 as expected

Comment: Consider accepting this answer if it finally worked for you :)